# Magento 2 : Where is product url key handled(crud) during product edit?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I'm debugging **url rewrites** in M2.

- One can change the product **url key** in **catalog/product/edit**  in the **Search Engine Optimization** tab
- I'm looking at `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save::execute` yet I see nothing related to url keys.
- **Q:** Who is in charge with of url_rewrites CURD? Where are url_rewrites handled during product update?

Answer (score 0):

> Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator::**getUrlPath()**
>   Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator::**getUrlPath()**

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to change product URL one is create plugin

of `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator::getUrlPath()`

Create a Observer for product save after event

create **events.xml** at below path

> app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

create **Productsaveafter.php** at below path

> app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_product->setUrlKey($url);
        $_product->save();    
    }   
}
```